# Get Date before current date change textview color

Tags: java, android

Hi Everyone I have got 3 columns Sqlite database into `ListView`. I'm trying to change of `TextView` of employee DOB (`empDobTxt`) color to red if the date given is before current date.

I'm following [this tutorial](http://androidopentutorials.com/android-sqlite-example/).

```
   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder = null;
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();

        holder.empIdTxt = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.txt_emp_id);
        holder.empNameTxt = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.txt_emp_name);
        holder.empDobTxt = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.txt_emp_dob);
        holder.empSalaryTxt = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.txt_emp_salary);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    Employee employee = (Employee) getItem(position);
    holder.empIdTxt.setText(employee.getId() + "");
    holder.empNameTxt.setText(employee.getName());
    holder.empSalaryTxt.setText(employee.getSalary() + "");
    holder.empDobTxt.setText(formatter.format(employee.getDateOfBirth()));

    String dtStart = empDobTxt.getText().toString(); 
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.ENGLISH);
    String currentDateandTime = sdf.format(new Date());
    try {  
        Date date = sdf.parse(dtStart);
        Date date1 = sdf.parse(currentDateandTime);
        if(date.before(date1));
        {
            empDobTxt.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        }  
    } catch (ParseException e) {  
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block  
        e.printStackTrace();  
    }

    return convertView;

}
```

This is `logCat`:

```
 02-17 11:33:00.486: E/AndroidRuntime(7308):        java.lang.NullPointerException
 02-17 11:33:00.486: E/AndroidRuntime(7308):    at  com.androidopentutorials.sqlite.adapter.EmpListAdapter.getView(EmpListAdapter.java:88)
```

Comment: what error you are getting post your logcat

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try to use `String dtStart = holder.empDobTxt.getText().toString();` instead of `String dtStart = empDobTxt.getText().toString();`

Also `holder.empDobTxt.setTextColor(Color.RED);` instead of `empDobTxt.setTextColor(Color.RED);`

You also have extra semicolon at this string

`if(date.before(date1));`

It is the reason why all your texts are red.

Comment: thanks for your reply.  it works but its always red, my point if its DOB after today color black

Comment: Try to remove extra semicolon from this string `if(date.before(date1));
        {
            empDobTxt.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        }  `

Comment: Yes, it is because you have extra semicolon symbol `;` after `if(date.before(date1));` statement. Just remove `;`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
String dtStart = empDobTxt.getText().toString(); 
try {  

    Calendar calDtStart = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy", Locale.EN_US);
    calDtStart.setTime(dtStart);

    Calendar nowDate = Calendar.getInstance();
    if(calDtStart.before(nowDate));
    {
        holder.empDobTxt.setTextColor(Color.RED);
    }  
} catch (ParseException e) {  
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block  
    e.printStackTrace();  
}
```

Comment: The method parse(String) in the type DateFormat is not applicable for the arguments (Calendar)

Comment: Updated with Calendar object, pls check